# Getting the same row multiple times out of a MultiIndexed DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Presume I have a MultiIndexed Dataframe and a regular one, for example

```
index = [['foo','foo','bar','bar'],['spam','eggs','spam','eggs']]
arr = np.arange(1,13).reshape((4,3))

df_multi = pd.DataFrame(arr, index = index)
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
```

If I were to require multiple rows from the regular DataFrame, I would do it as follows:

```
request = [0,0,1,0,1,2]
rows = df.loc[request]
```

The `rows` object is a new DataFrame, where each row comes from `df` in the order defined by `request`, the key part for me here is that the order of `request` remains and I can get the same row as many times as I require by requesting it multiple times.

But if I were to do the same thing with MultiIndexed DataFrame:

```
request = (['foo','foo', 'foo'], ['spam', 'eggs', 'spam'])
rows    = df_multi.loc(axis=0)[request]
```

I would get only the unique rows from my request and they would be sorted.
Where as what I expect is that the situation would be just like in the previous case, unsorted and repeated as requested.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an iterable of tuples defining each row's MultiIndex value, e.g. using `zip(*request)`:

```py
rows = df_multi.loc[zip(*request)]
rows

Out[51]: 
          0  1  2
foo spam  1  2  3
    eggs  4  5  6
    spam  1  2  3
```

Note: `list(zip(*request))` evaluates to

```
[('foo', 'spam'), ('foo', 'eggs'), ('foo', 'spam')]
```